# Default Generic Type

Tags: java, generics

Say I have the following generic class:

```
public class Foo<T extends Bar> {
   // stuff
}
```

Is it possible to specify a default type(`Baz`, for instance), which would act as `T` if no `T` were passed in?

Comment: No, but what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. See ["Type Variables"](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#108850) in the Java Language Specification.

That said, you can provide subclasses which accomplish a similar purpose:

```
public class Foo<T extends Bar> { ... }

public class FooDefault extends Foo< Baz > { ... }
```

Comment: Is it maybe possible with an annotation processor?

Comment: No, never used them before, was just wondering. But it will probably end up being just a fancy, complicated version of a factory method.

Answer (score 2):

Use factory method like

```
public <T extends Bar> static Foo<T> getInstance(Class<T> clz) { 
    if (clz == null) 
        return new Foo<Bar>; 
    else 
        return clz.newInstance();
}
```

Comment: I think you meant the last line to create a Foo.

Comment: yup, really, sorry about that :) Anyway the idea should be clear

Comment: You can fix your answer through its "edit" link at the lower left.